# How to search for a specific word from a string and display them

Tags: java

I am parsing a response from imgur. The below is the response that is stored as a single link.

```
{"data":{"id":"uzgZm0q","title":null,"description":null,"datetime":1468223393,"type":"image\/png","animated":false,"width":267,"height":189,"size":95089,"views":0,"bandwidth":0,"vote":null,"favorite":false,"nsfw":null,"section":null,"account_url":null,"account_id":0,"in_gallery":false,"deletehash":"IJbIGyD5tZFnxrJ","name":"","link":"http:\/\/i.imgur.com\/uzgZm0q.png"},"success":true,"status":200}
```

How can I take out the id or the link in the response?

I do not want to convert the string to JSON and then get the response. I would like to keep the response as a String itself.

Comment: With a JSON parser.

Comment: I don't want to convert it into JSON. I want to work with it as a String itself.

Comment: Then you will end up writing a JSON parser. Because... it's JSON data, and you're trying to parse it.

Answer (score -1):

You can either convert it into POJO.
Or
You can use REGEX.

You can use a regex like `/"\bid\b":"/` or `/"\blink\b":"/` which is of the form `/"\b[KEY]\b":"/` to get the index of your desired value and then extract the rest of the string as substring to again use this regex `\.+?(?=")\` for your desired result.

Example:

when you use `/"\bid\b":"/` on `{"id":"abcdefgh","anything":something"}`, you get the index of **"id":"**. Use this index to extract the rest of the substring which will be `abcdefgh","anything":something"}`.

Now using `\.+?(?=")\` will give you **abcdefgh**

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to use REGEX for this particular case. I don't want to convert it into JSON.

Comment: I have added the example for your case.
You can check it try it on http://regexr.com/